# Understand lattice definition and volume , algebraic number theory

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am taking the course algebraic number theory ( book J. Neukirch algebraic number theory ) and we reached a point where we are talking about the lattice I know that a lattice is a discrete subgroup of a vector space like for example $\mathbb{R}^2$ a lattice is $\mathbb{Z}^2$ so we can pick any two linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and they will construct a lattice? On $\mathbb{R}^2$ ? And the volume is the area of the parallelogram?

The volume of is defined related to a basis for the subgroup to be the determinant of the basis matrix this in ( An introduction to the Geometry of numbers J.W.S. Cassels) but in Neukirch book the volume is the root of the determinant of the dot product of the basis vectors! 
So if I pick different linearly independent vectors I will get different volumes $<3,0>,<0,-5>$ the volume is 15 but if I pick the standard basis it is 1. And the book said the volume does not depend on the basis how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember here basis means two elements $u,v$ of the lattice $L$ such that any element of $L$ is obtainable from them as **integer linear combination**. So two different basis are related by an integer matrix of determinant $\pm1$. If we stick to ordered basis then the sign can be managed.

What you call standard basis may not belong to the Lattice and so there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I see thank you, what about the definition of the volume is it just the determinant of the basis vectors?

Comment: For vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ in $\mathbf R^n$, let $A$ be the matrix with those vectors as its columns.  Then the product $M = A^\top A$ has its $(i,j)$ entry equal to the dot product $v_i \cdot v_j$.  And $\det M = \det(A^\top A) = \det(A^\top)\det(A) = \det(A)^2$.  Thus $|\det(A)| = \sqrt{\det M} = \sqrt{\det((v_i \cdot v_j))}$. That is how the absolute value of the determinant of a matrix can be written as the square root of the determinant of a matrix of dot products.